# Dynamically add WebView to Dynamically Created Tab

Tags: android, dynamic, webview

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    actbar=getActionBar();



    actbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    Tab tb= actbar.newTab();
    tb.setText("1");
    tb.setTabListener(this);
    WebView wv= new WebView(this);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://203.90.76.206/newmis/Reports/OOH%20Screens/1.htm");
    // I want to add this webview to Tab tb

    actbar.addTab(tb);
    }
```

As shown in above code, I am dynamically adding a tab to an actionbar. Now what I want to do more is to create a dynamic webview and add it to the Tab.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add a webview to a tabbar... See also https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs for a detailed description about correct use of the tabbar in Android.

Comment: Sir, I Mean inside Tabpage not in tabar